# How to use Spring OAuth2 Client in SPA and multi-node application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I want to implement a feature that user connects his account with external applications (similar feature is in Facebook). User has to log in to external application and grant permission to access data by my application.

Once user connected an external app, data will be exchanged in background using access and refresh tokens.

Application architecture is:

- SPA front-end (Angular)
- REST API (Spring), multiple nodes
- ScyllaDB
- Envoy proxy (with JWT verification)

The first idea is to use Spring OAuth2 Client. However, some changes need to be made:

- there is no Principal because JWT is verified by Envoy proxy and X-USER-ID header is added
- REST API is stateless and we shouldn't store authorization code in session
- even with sessions, there are multiple nodes and we need to share authorization code between nodes
- custom URL, e.g. /app_name/connect instead of /oauth2/authorization/app_name
- redirect URL may be invalid (but it's verified by Spring's filter)

How this could work:

- user click "Connect with app" in SPA
- SPA redirects user to /oauth2/authorization/app_name (or custom URL)
- Spring redirects user to external app's authentication server
- user authenticates and grants permissions
- external app redirects user back to Spring (or straight to SPA?)
- Spring redirects user back to SPA (or SPA sends access token to REST API?)

Despite Spring Security components can be replaced, many of them are coupled and you need to rewrite OAuth2 Client flow almost from scratch. Maybe I'm doing something wrong and it can be achieved easier.

What I already did:

```java
http
      .cors().and()
      .csrf().disable()
      .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and()
      .oauth2Client(); // get rid of these two filters?
```

```java
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OAuth2ClientConfig {

  private final CassandraTemplate cassandraTemplate;

  // overriding original client service - we need to store tokens in database
  @Bean
  public OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService(
    CassandraTemplate cassandraTemplate,
    ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
    return new ScyllaOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(cassandraTemplate, clientRegistrationRepository);
  }

  // configure client provider to use authorization code with refresh token
  @Bean
  public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
    ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
    OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {

    var authorizedClientProvider =
      OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
        .authorizationCode()
        .refreshToken()
        .build();

    var authorizedClientManager = new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
      clientRegistrationRepository,
      authorizedClientRepository);
    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

    return authorizedClientManager;
  }

  // the specs recommend to use WebClient for exchanging data instead of RestTemplate
  @Bean
  public WebClient webClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
    ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Client =
      new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
    return WebClient.builder()
      .apply(oauth2Client.oauth2Configuration())
      .build();
  }

  // override request repository - and I'm stuck there
  @Bean
  public AuthorizationRequestRepository<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest> authorizationRequestRepository() {
    return new ScyllaOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository(cassandraTemplate);
  }

}
```

Because there are multiple nodes of REST API, we can't use sessions. We need to store request somewhere, e.g. ScyllaDB, Redis, Hazelcast, etc. I decided to store it as JSON in ScyllaDB but I ran into trouble.

```java
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public final class ScyllaOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository implements AuthorizationRequestRepository<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest> {

  private final CassandraTemplate cassandraTemplate;
  private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

  @Override
  public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest loadAuthorizationRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Assert.notNull(request, "request cannot be null");
    var stateParameter = this.getStateParameter(request);
    if (stateParameter == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return this.getAuthorizationRequest(request, stateParameter);
  }

  @Override
  public void saveAuthorizationRequest(OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest, HttpServletRequest request,
                                       HttpServletResponse response) {
    Assert.notNull(request, "request cannot be null");
    Assert.notNull(response, "response cannot be null");
    if (authorizationRequest == null) {
      this.removeAuthorizationRequest(request, response);
      return;
    }
    var state = authorizationRequest.getState();
    var userId = UUID.fromString(request.getHeader(Constants.USER_ID));
    Assert.hasText(state, "authorizationRequest.state cannot be empty");
    try {
      // serialization of Auth2AuthorizationRequest to JSON works
      cassandraTemplate.getCqlOperations().execute("insert into oauth2_requests (user_id,state,data) values (?,?,?)",
        userId, state, objectMapper.writeValueAsString(authorizationRequest));
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      log.warn("Unable to save authorization request", e);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest removeAuthorizationRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Assert.notNull(request, "request cannot be null");
    var stateParameter = this.getStateParameter(request);
    if (stateParameter == null) {
      return null;
    }
    var userId = UUID.fromString(request.getHeader(Constants.USER_ID));
    var originalRequest = this.getAuthorizationRequest(request, stateParameter);
    cassandraTemplate.getCqlOperations().execute("delete from oauth2_requests where user_id=? and state=?",
      userId, stateParameter);
    return originalRequest;
  }

  private String getStateParameter(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getParameter(OAuth2ParameterNames.STATE);
  }

  private UUID getUserId(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return UUID.fromString(request.getHeader(Constants.USER_ID));
  }

  private OAuth2AuthorizationRequest getAuthorizationRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String state) {
    var userId = getUserId(request);
    var jsonRequest = cassandraTemplate.getCqlOperations().queryForObject(
      "select data from oauth2_requests where user_id=? and state=?", String.class, userId, state);
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(jsonRequest)) {
      try {
        // trying to mess with OAuth2ClientJackson2Module
        var objectMapper = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().autoDetectFields(true)
          .autoDetectGettersSetters(true)
          .modules(new OAuth2ClientJackson2Module())
          .visibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
          .build();
        return objectMapper.readValue(jsonRequest, OAuth2AuthorizationRequest.class);
      } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        log.warn("Error decoding authentication request", e);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

I get error when trying to deserialize JSON to OAuth2AuthorizationRequest:

```
Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationRequest]: missing type id property '@class'
```

Without adding OAuth2ClientJackson2Module there is another error:

```
Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationResponseType` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

By the way, OAuth2ClientJackson2Module seems never used in original filters.

Maybe it's better to serialize this object Java way and store it as BLOB or do not store request in database but somewhere other.

Another part is the controller action:

```java
  // it had to be /apps/app_name/connect but in Spring OAuth2 Client it's hardcoded to append provider name at the end
  @GetMapping("/apps/connect/app_name")
  public void connect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    userAppService.authorize(request, response, "app_name");
  }
```

To get rid of filters which verify redirect URL and have many things hardcoded:

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserAppService {

  private final HttpSecurity httpSecurity;
  private final AuthenticationDetailsSource<HttpServletRequest, ?> authenticationDetailsSource = new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource();
  private final AuthorizationRequestRepository<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest> authorizationRequestRepository;
  private final ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;
  private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager;
  private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository;
  private final RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

  public void authorize(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String appName) throws IOException {
    var userId = UUID.fromString(request.getHeader(Constants.USER_ID));
    var authorizeRequest = OAuth2AuthorizeRequest
      .withClientRegistrationId(appName)
      .principal(UUIDPrincipal.fromUserId(userId))
      .build();
    if (isAuthorizationResponse(request)) {
      var authorizationRequest = this.authorizationRequestRepository.loadAuthorizationRequest(request);
      if (authorizationRequest != null) {
        processAuthorizationRequest(request, response);
      }
    } else {
      try {
        OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = authorizedClientManager.authorize(authorizeRequest);
        if (authorizedClient != null) {
          OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = authorizedClient.getAccessToken();
          System.out.println(accessToken);
        }
      } catch (ClientAuthorizationException e) {
        // in this URL provider name is appended at the end and no way to change this behavior
        var authorizationRequestResolver = new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(clientRegistrationRepository,
          "/apps/connect");
        var authorizationRequest = authorizationRequestResolver.resolve(request);
        this.authorizationRequestRepository.saveAuthorizationRequest(authorizationRequest, request, response);
        this.redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, authorizationRequest.getAuthorizationRequestUri());
      }
    }
  }

  private void processAuthorizationRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    var authorizationRequest = this.authorizationRequestRepository.removeAuthorizationRequest(request, response);
    var registrationId = (String) authorizationRequest.getAttribute(OAuth2ParameterNames.REGISTRATION_ID);
    var clientRegistration = this.clientRegistrationRepository.findByRegistrationId(registrationId);
    var params = toMultiMap(request.getParameterMap());
    var redirectUri = UrlUtils.buildFullRequestUrl(request);
    var authorizationResponse = convert(params, redirectUri);
    var authenticationRequest = new OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationToken(
      clientRegistration, new OAuth2AuthorizationExchange(authorizationRequest, authorizationResponse));
    authenticationRequest.setDetails(this.authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(request));
    OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationToken authenticationResult;
    try {
      var authenticationManager = httpSecurity.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class);
      authenticationResult = (OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationToken) authenticationManager
        .authenticate(authenticationRequest);
    } catch (OAuth2AuthorizationException ex) {
      OAuth2Error error = ex.getError();
      UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(authorizationRequest.getRedirectUri())
        .queryParam(OAuth2ParameterNames.ERROR, error.getErrorCode());
      if (!StringUtils.hasText(error.getDescription())) {
        uriBuilder.queryParam(OAuth2ParameterNames.ERROR_DESCRIPTION, error.getDescription());
      }
      if (!StringUtils.hasText(error.getUri())) {
        uriBuilder.queryParam(OAuth2ParameterNames.ERROR_URI, error.getUri());
      }
      this.redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, uriBuilder.build().encode().toString());
      return;
    }
    // just copy-paste of original filter - trying to understand what's happening there
    Authentication currentAuthentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String principalName = (currentAuthentication != null) ? currentAuthentication.getName() : "anonymousUser";
    OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = new OAuth2AuthorizedClient(
      authenticationResult.getClientRegistration(), principalName, authenticationResult.getAccessToken(),
      authenticationResult.getRefreshToken());
    this.authorizedClientRepository.saveAuthorizedClient(authorizedClient, currentAuthentication, request,
      response);
    String redirectUrl = authorizationRequest.getRedirectUri();
    this.redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, redirectUrl);
  }

  private static boolean isAuthorizationResponse(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return isAuthorizationResponseSuccess(request) || isAuthorizationResponseError(request);
  }

  private static boolean isAuthorizationResponseSuccess(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return StringUtils.hasText(request.getParameter(OAuth2ParameterNames.CODE))
      && StringUtils.hasText(request.getParameter(OAuth2ParameterNames.STATE));
  }

  private static boolean isAuthorizationResponseError(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return StringUtils.hasText(request.getParameter(OAuth2ParameterNames.ERROR))
      && StringUtils.hasText(request.getParameter(OAuth2ParameterNames.STATE));
  }

  // copy paste - not tested this code yet
  static MultiValueMap<String, String> toMultiMap(Map<String, String[]> map) {
    MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>(map.size());
    map.forEach((key, values) -> {
      if (values.length > 0) {
        for (String value : values) {
          params.add(key, value);
        }
      }
    });
    return params;
  }

  static OAuth2AuthorizationResponse convert(MultiValueMap<String, String> request, String redirectUri) {
    String code = request.getFirst(OAuth2ParameterNames.CODE);
    String errorCode = request.getFirst(OAuth2ParameterNames.ERROR);
    String state = request.getFirst(OAuth2ParameterNames.STATE);
    if (StringUtils.hasText(code)) {
      return OAuth2AuthorizationResponse.success(code).redirectUri(redirectUri).state(state).build();
    }
    String errorDescription = request.getFirst(OAuth2ParameterNames.ERROR_DESCRIPTION);
    String errorUri = request.getFirst(OAuth2ParameterNames.ERROR_URI);
    return OAuth2AuthorizationResponse.error(errorCode)
      .redirectUri(redirectUri)
      .errorDescription(errorDescription)
      .errorUri(errorUri)
      .state(state)
      .build();
  }

}
```

Client service to stored authorized clients in database:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ScyllaOAuth2AuthorizedClientService implements OAuth2AuthorizedClientService {

  private final CassandraTemplate cassandraTemplate;
  private final ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

  @Override
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public OAuth2AuthorizedClient loadAuthorizedClient(String clientRegistrationId, String principal) {
    var id = BasicMapId.id("userId", principal).with("appCode", clientRegistrationId);
    var userApp = cassandraTemplate.selectOneById(id, UserApp.class);
    if (userApp != null) {
      var clientRegistration = getClientRegistration(clientRegistrationId);
      var accessToken = getAccessToken(userApp);
      var refreshToken = getRefreshToken(userApp);
      return new OAuth2AuthorizedClient(clientRegistration, principal, accessToken, refreshToken);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void saveAuthorizedClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient, Authentication principal) {
    Assert.notNull(authorizedClient, "authorizedClient cannot be null");
    Assert.notNull(principal, "principal cannot be null");
    var userApp = new UserApp();
    userApp.setUserId((UUID) principal.getPrincipal());
    userApp.setAppCode(authorizedClient.getClientRegistration().getClientId());
    if (authorizedClient.getAccessToken() != null) {
      userApp.setAccessToken(authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue());
      userApp.setAccessTokenType(OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType.BEARER.getValue());
      userApp.setAccessTokenScopes(authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getScopes());
      userApp.setAccessTokenIssuedAt(authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getIssuedAt());
      userApp.setAccessTokenExpiresAt(authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getExpiresAt());
    }
    if (authorizedClient.getRefreshToken() != null) {
      userApp.setRefreshToken(authorizedClient.getRefreshToken().getTokenValue());
      userApp.setRefreshTokenIssuedAt(authorizedClient.getRefreshToken().getIssuedAt());
      userApp.setRefreshTokenExpiresAt(authorizedClient.getRefreshToken().getExpiresAt());
    }
    cassandraTemplate.insert(userApp);
  }

  @Override
  public void removeAuthorizedClient(String clientRegistrationId, String principal) {
    var id = BasicMapId.id("userId", principal).with("appCode", clientRegistrationId);
    cassandraTemplate.deleteById(id, UserApp.class);
  }

  private ClientRegistration getClientRegistration(String clientRegistrationId) {
    var clientRegistration = this.clientRegistrationRepository.findByRegistrationId(clientRegistrationId);
    if (clientRegistration == null) {
      throw new DataRetrievalFailureException(
        "The ClientRegistration with id '" + clientRegistrationId + "' exists in the data source, "
          + "however, it was not found in the ClientRegistrationRepository.");
    }
    return clientRegistration;
  }

  private OAuth2AccessToken getAccessToken(UserApp userApp) {
    return new OAuth2AccessToken(
      OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType.BEARER,
      userApp.getAccessToken(),
      userApp.getAccessTokenIssuedAt(),
      userApp.getAccessTokenExpiresAt(),
      userApp.getAccessTokenScopes());
  }

  private OAuth2RefreshToken getRefreshToken(UserApp userApp) {
    return new OAuth2RefreshToken(userApp.getRefreshToken(), userApp.getRefreshTokenIssuedAt());
  }
}
```

Too much code overwrite. I need to make it as simple as possible.

Currently I'm struggling with storing authorize request in database.

How to do it Spring way but to keep the app architecture given at the beginning of this question?

Any way to configure OAuth2 Client without hardcoded URL like /oauth2/authorization/provider_name?

Maybe it's better to do the whole OAuth2 flow client-side (within SPA) and the SPA should send access and request token to REST API (to store the tokens in order to be able to exchange data with external app)?

Comment: `missing type id property '@class'` means that `OAuth2AuthorizationRequest` was not serialized properly. Check your JSON. It should start with this: `{"@class":"org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationRequest","authorizationUri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth","authorizationGrantType":{"value":"authorization_code"}...` and not with this: `{"authorizationUri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth","responseType":{"value":"code"},...` It's probably because you didn't register Spring Security modules (see `SecurityJackson2Modules`).

Answer (score 0):

In OAuth2 wording, REST APIs are **resource-servers**, not clients.

What you can do is have

- your proxy be transparent to OAuth2 (forward requests with their JWT access-token authorization header and responses status code)
- configure each REST API as resource-server. Tutorials there: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials.
- add an OAuth2 client library to your Angular app to handle tokens and authorize requests. My favorite is [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client)
- probably use an intermediate authorization-server for identity federation (Google, Facebook, etc., but also internal DB, LDAP, or whatever is needed), roles management, MFA,... Keycloak is a famous "on premise" solution, but you can search for "OIDC authorization-server" in your favorite search engine and have plenty of alternate choices, including SaaS like Auth0 or Amazon Cognito.

This is fully compatible with distributed architectures and micro-services (session-less is the default configuration  for resource-servers in the tutorials I linked).

Two cases for a micro-service delegating some of its processing to another resource-server:

- the "child" request is made on behalf of the user who initiated the request => retrieve original access-token from `Authentication` instance in security-context and forward it (set it as Bearer authorization header for the sub-request)
- the "child" request is not made on behalf of a user => client-credentials must be used (the micro-services acquires a new access-token in its own name to authorize the sub request). Refer to `spring-boot-oauth2-client` and your preferred REST client docs for details (`WebClient`, `@FeignClient`, `RestTemplate`).